# jQuery Mobile: some button icons do not show up

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile locally (not from CDN) and everything worked fine until now.
I want to change the icons of some buttons as described here, but some icons (e.g. bars and edit) do not work.

Update: Tried the CDN files, which doesn't work either.

If I use for example this code:

```
<div data-role="content">
  <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="edit">My button</a>
</div>
```

The button gets rendered with a plus icon.
The strange thing is that some icons (like plus, arrow-u, arrow-d, forward and check) work just fine.
Does someone have any suggestions what could have went wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

```
./:     index.html
./css:  jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css   jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css
./css/images: ajax-loader.gif  icons-18-white.png  icons-36-white.png  icons-18-black.png  icons-36-black.png
./js:   custom-scripting.js  jquery-1.8.3.min.js  jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js  jquery-1.8.3.js    jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js
```

The head of my html file looks like this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
  <script src="./js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/custom-scripting.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: `./` is the same as if you didn't write anything. You you could just use  `src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"`

Comment: Link the website in question please, not sure if you can but we need more information, link of the CSS on the button would be nice! assuming the button CSS is loading.

Comment: I removed the minimal example since the questions seems to be answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bars and Edit icons were just added to jQuery Mobile a month ago https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5340

These icons are not in the latest stable version of jQuery Mobile (1.2.0)  You can get these if you use the [latest versions of jQuery Mobile](http://jsbin.com/opigaj/1/edit) or wait till jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 comes out.

Comment: @seba229 If this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it for the benefit of others who may have the same problem in the future. You can accept this answer by clicking the check-mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set background-position of ui-icon-edit class in your CSS file (jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css), e.g:

```
.ui-icon-edit {background-position: -288px 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But why do I have to set this? Shouldn't jQuery mobile provide the background positions for all available icons?

Comment: Seems like they removed some icons but did not update the documentation. The edit icon is not present in the sprite file(s).

Comment: @seba229 I don't develop on jquery mobile but ya surely mobile CSS should have this setted somewhere but cannot find it even in official CSS file.